# Pandas: speeding up groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am wondering whether it is possible to speed up pandas `dataframe.groupby` with the following application:

Basic data structure:

- HDFStore with 9 columns
- 4 columns are columns with data (`colF` ... `colI`)
- the combination of the remaining 5 columns (`colA` ... `colE`) gives a unique index
- `colE` is a "last modified" column

The basic idea is to implement a data base with a "transactional memory". Assuming an entry changes, I don't delete it but write a new row with a new value in the "last modified" column. This allows me to retroactively look at how entries have changed over time.

However, in situations where I only want the currently valid "state" of the data, it requires selecting only those rows with the most recent "last modified" column:

```
idx = df.groupby(['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD'], 
                 as_index=False, sort=False)['colE'].max()
df_current_state = df.merge(idx, 'inner', on=['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE'])
```

This `groupby` method eats up about 70% of my run time.

Note: For the majority of rows, there exists only a single entry with respect to the "last modified" column. Only for very few, multiple versions of the row with different "last modified" values exist.

**Is there a way to speed up this process other than changing the program logic as follows?**

---

### Alternative Solution without need for `groupby`:

Add an additional "boolean" column `activeState` which stores whether the row is part of the "active state".

When rows change, mark their `activeState` field as `False` and insert a new row with `activeState=True`.

One can then query the table with `activeState==True` rather than use `groupby`.

My issue with this solution is that it has the potential for mistakes where the `activeState` field is not set appropriately. Of course this is recoverable from using the "last modified" column, but if the `groupby` could be sped up, it would be foolproof...

Comment: Is the dataframe already sorted on the groupby cols? If not, sorting them and then putting them in an index might be one way to squeeze out some performance.

Comment: @PaulH Currently it is not. Sounds like a possibility but I suppose it requires re-sorting the entire database everytime a single entry changes. - If so, dumping a filtered version might be less of a hassle. What do you think?

Comment: I would just sort the data frame not the hdf5 file.

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for clarifying. That sounds much more feasible. I am going to give it a go and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

What about using a sort followed by drop_duplicates?  I'm using it on a large database with four levels of grouping with good speed.  Im taking the first, so I don't know how first vs last helps the speed, but you can always reverse the sort too.

```
df_current_state = df.sort(columns='colE')
df_current_state = df_current_state.drop_duplicates(subset=['colA','colB','colC','colD'],take_last=True)
```